# LibGDX - Load a TiledMap tileset from a big TextureRegion

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, tiled, texturepacker

I'm currently developing a game using LibGDX and I have come to the following situation:

1. The game uses `TiledMap` maps for each level in it. I created a large tile set and packed it to a ~1300x1300 PNG file (non-POT). Tiles are 128x128 + gutter.
2. The scene is rendered using an `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer`. Actually it is a slight modification of the built-in `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer`, which does not set the camera projection to the `SpriteBatch` renderer, causing an extra flush each loop:

   ```
   private class OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer2 extends OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer {
       public OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer2 (TiledMap map, float unitScale, Batch batch) {
           super(map, unitScale, batch);
       }

       @Override
       public void setView (OrthographicCamera camera) {
           //batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined); //This causes an unneeded flush in my case: the projection matrix is already set.
           float width = camera.viewportWidth * camera.zoom;
           float height = camera.viewportHeight * camera.zoom;
           viewBounds.set(camera.position.x - width / 2, camera.position.y - height / 2, width, height);
       }
   }
   ```
3. I draw several other objects (enemies, items, active elements) before I start rendering the tiledMap. This has to be this way since there are not tiles on all the cells of the map, and I want these objects to hide under some tiles. All this objects share the same camera projection, so I start the `SpriteBatch` when I want to render these objects, and leave it open when I start the map renderer. All these objects are currently packed into a texture about 1000x1000 in size, but it is comprised of lots of small objects so they can be wrapped around the tileset's region (read below). So the thing goes:

   ```
   @Override
   public void render(float delta) {
       Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
       Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

       batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
       batch.begin();
       for (Thing t : things) {
           t.draw(batch);
       }
       orthogonalTiledMapRenderer2.setView(camera);
       orthogonalTiledMapRenderer2.render(tileLayer); //Uses the same batch
       //...
        batch.end();
    }
   ```

Now, the thing is clear: My plan is to pack everything into a single Power-Of-Two texture (to the affordable size of 2048x2048), both the `TiledMap` tile set and the objects sheet, so I use a single texture and I can minimize batch flushes to the GPU. The problem is I can't find a way of loading a `TiledMap` using an external `SpriteRegion`, not even using the `AtlasTmxTiledMapLoader`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is there a way to load a `TiledMap` passing a `TextureRegion` as the tileset, instead of creating a new, unreachable `Texture`, and having to flush once for the map and again for the rest of your sprites?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this, but you ought to be able to pass your single Power-Of-Two texture atlas into using the map-level property 'atlas' as long as the regions are named apropiately.

From the Javadoc...

> public class AtlasTmxMapLoader extends BaseTmxMapLoader
>
> A TiledMap Loader which loads tiles from a TextureAtlas instead of
>   separate images. It requires a map-level property called 'atlas' with
>   its value being the relative path to the TextureAtlas. The atlas must
>   have in it indexed regions named after the tilesets used in the map.
>   The indexes shall be local to the tileset (not the global id). Strip
>   whitespace and rotation should not be used when creating the atlas.

Comment: I've tried this, but the problem is this method requires to have each different tile as a single file at the moment of packing the textures. As a programmer, what I'm currently getting from the design team is just the big tile set they pack. Also, what you use in TilEd is this big one-file-tileset. And what about the gutter? I'm finding lots of inconveniences, I'm looking for a way of taking advantage of what's done already, not having to mess around with hundreds of individual tiles.

Comment: Why not write a program to split them out? Or hand-craft your own atlas file? Or even simply ask the design team to provide separate files.

Comment: Well, I wrote the program. Now I have all the tiles (from the tilemap and the objects) in a single file. Now I'm having a hard time trying to use the atlas both on the TiledMap and the rest of the game. Yikes...